# how can i pass a string variable in json by using GET method

Tags: c#, json, ajax

When I receive a string value as an object then return false calls and output getting null in controller.

How to fix this?

How can I pass a string variable in json??

Here is the code:

```
function EditRow(obj) {
 debugger
 //var jSon = JSON.stringify(obj);
 //data: { "LocationId": obj },
 $.ajax({
  url: "/TLocation/EditLocation/",
  type: "GET",
  cache: true,
  //async: true,
  //data: JSON.stringify({ LocationId: obj }),
  //data: { "LocationId": obj },
  data: {
   LocationId: JSON.stringify(obj)
  },
  success: function(result) {
   $("#EditLocation").html(result);
  },
  error: function(result) {
   alert('');
  }
 });
 return false;
}
obj = "Test"
```

Here is the controller:

```
[System.Web.Services.WebMethod]
        public ActionResult EditLocation(string LocationId)
        {
            try
            {
                if (Session["Type"] == null)
                    return RedirectToAction("Index", "Account");
                var model = new TLocationModel();

                LocationBL objloc = new LocationBL();
                //model.IsEmailDublicate = "0";

                if (LocationId.Length > 0)
                {
                    var Item = objloc.getLocationById(LocationId);
                    if (Item != null)
                    {
                        model.LocationID = Item.LocationID != null ? Item.LocationID : "";
                        model.Description = Item.Description != null ? Item.Description : "";
                        model.Category = Item.Category != null ? Item.Category : "";
                        model.Aisle = Item.Aisle != null ? Item.Aisle : "";
                        model.Self = Item.Shelf != null ? Item.Shelf : "";
                        model.Bin = Item.Bin != null ? Item.Bin : "";
                        model.PrintBarcode = Item.PrintBarcode != null ? Item.PrintBarcode.Value : false;
                    }

                }
                return PartialView("EditLocation", model);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw ex;
            }
        }
```

Comment: Is this a "get" request?

Comment: yes sir..it is a get request

Comment: pass parameter in query string `url: "/TLocation/EditLocation?LocationId=" + obj`

Comment: sir the output comes undefined thatmeans in controller LocationId got undefined

Comment: Change URL in the ajax call as `url: "/TLocation/EditLocation?LocationId="+obj, `

Comment: i have already changes..but not working

Comment: it will throw null, from where you are getting the LocationID?

Comment: i have getting the string value in obj i.e. function EditRow(obj)

Comment: try this  code=>       data: {   LocationId: obj  },

Comment: you can call your action in ajax call without  [System.Web.Services.WebMethod].why you use it?

Comment: no data: { LocationId: obj }, simply not working

Comment: I think your 'obj' variable in JavaScript contains an HTML tag (the input tag)and not a location Id. Try getting the value out of it using `var locationId = $(obj).val()`. Then put `locationId` in the URL, something like `/TLocation/EditLocation/` + locationId.

Comment: yes in obj i am getting xyz and in locationId i am getting mnp..but i want xyz..which is coming just like input#xyz..yes what should i do..if i am using var locationId = $(obj).val() it will sending the id,but instead of id i want value(obj:input#xyz)..

Comment: @SteveCooper how to get only obj from the locationId

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change URL in the ajax call and remove the data parameter

```
function EditRow(obj) {
debugger
//var jSon = JSON.stringify(obj);
//data: { "LocationId": obj },
$.ajax({
 url: "/TLocation/EditLocation/LocationId=" + obj,
 type: "GET",
 cache: true,
 //async: true,
 //data: JSON.stringify({ LocationId: obj }),
 //data: { "LocationId": obj },
 success: function(result) {
 $("#EditLocation").html(result);
 },
 error: function(result) {
 alert('');
}
});
return false;
}
obj = "Test"
```

Comment: output getting [object HTMLInputElement]..instead of any string value

Comment: Put a debug point in the EditLocation function and check if you are getting the `LocationId` or not?

Comment: where should i put the debugger??i have already put a debugger

Comment: If you dont know how to use debugger, then only return `model.Descritption` and see if you are getting it in the HTML

Comment: sir i have already getting the value in obj i.e. function EditRow(obj)......the problem is that how can i send a string value

Comment: Thats what i am telling! Change the ajax call ! Let me update the code once

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/122167/discussion-between-manoj-maharana-and-richa-garg).

Comment: the output will be some thing like  [object HTMLInputElement

Comment: in controller getting output getting [object HTMLInputElement]. instead of value

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/122176/discussion-between-manoj-maharana-and-richa-garg).

Answer (score 0):

Write your controller function like this. If LocationId has a proper JSON structure the *values* list will show you the data contained:

```
public ActionResult EditLocation(string LocationId)
{
try
{
    if (Session["Type"] == null)
        return RedirectToAction("Index", "Account");
    var model = new TLocationModel();

    LocationBL objloc = new LocationBL();
    //model.IsEmailDublicate = "0";

    JObject JLocationId = JObject.Parse(LocationId);
    IEnumerable<object> values = JLocationId.Values();
    foreach (var x in values)
    {
        //Console.WriteLine(x) or something like that to check the values of the JSON object
    }

    if (LocationId.Count > 0)
    {
        var Item = objloc.getLocationById(LocationId);
        if (Item != null)
        {
            model.LocationID = Item.LocationID != null ? Item.LocationID : "";
            model.Description = Item.Description != null ? Item.Description : "";
            model.Category = Item.Category != null ? Item.Category : "";
            model.Aisle = Item.Aisle != null ? Item.Aisle : "";
            model.Self = Item.Shelf != null ? Item.Shelf : "";
            model.Bin = Item.Bin != null ? Item.Bin : "";
            model.PrintBarcode = Item.PrintBarcode != null ? Item.PrintBarcode.Value : false;
        }

    }
    return PartialView("EditLocation", model);
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    throw ex;
}
```

}

Comment: what is this??what should i do?

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I'd try. It's full of checks to make sure it's getting the right input, so take the checks out if it solves the problem. Otherwise, it may help you track down the issue;

```
function EditRow(obj) {

    // expect 'obj' to be a string, since this is what is declared in the C# method
    if (obj === undefined) { throw "obj undefined"; }
    if (obj === null ) { throw "obj null"; }
    if (obj instanceof jQuery) { throw "Got a JQuery object"; }
    if (obj instanceof Element) { throw "Got an HTML element"; }

    // NEW EDIT
    if (typeof(obj) !== "string") { 
         throw "Did not have a string; had a " + typeof(obj) + " like " + JSON.stringify(obj, null, 4); 
    }

    console.log("Looks like a string of length " + obj.length, obj);

    var url = "/TLocation/EditLocation/LocationId=" + obj;

    console.log("URL is " + url);

    $.ajax({
        url: url,
        type: "GET",
        cache: true,
        success: function(result) {
            $("#EditLocation").html(result);
        },
        error: function(result) {
            alert('');
        }
    });

    return false;
}
```

If you can tell us precisely the error you see in the debug window of your browser, that will help us sort out the issue.

Comment: sir error is here:TLocation:764 Uncaught Did not have a string; had a object............. if (typeof(obj) !== "string") { throw "Did not have a string; had a " + typeof(obj); }   in this line ...............near  + typeof(obj);.....what should  i do??

Comment: OK, good. What that means is that your code is expecting a string, but that's not what has been passed into the function. `obj` doesn't seem to be an HTML element or a jQuery object, so we need to find out what it is. I think you need to edit your original post, and add in the code that calls `EditRow`. This will help us see what is going into the function. Also, I'll update the answer with an extra line or two, which may help us track down the kind of object you are passing.

Comment: Let me know what error you get when you run the code above, which I've just changed a little bit.

Comment: sir in  obj i am getting input#Alderman1..but i want onlt Alderman1 from the obj

Comment: Can you oost the code that calls EditRow() ? I think the problem is there. I'm not sure what kind of object `input#Alderman1` is, because it's not a string, a JQuery object, or an HTML element, so I'm a little bit stuck. Please post the code which calls EditRow() so we can see what kind of thing `obj` is.

Comment: (Also, just fixed the syntax error in my code which said `instanceOf` but should have said `instanceof`. Did you correct this or comment out the lines?)

Comment: '<a class=\"\" href=\"#\" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#EditTLocationModal" onclick=\"EditRow(' + oObj.aData[0] + ');\" title=\"Edit Row\"><img src=\"/Content/images/circle_info_small_blue.png\" style=\"width: 15px;\" /></a><a style=\"display: none\" data-toggle=\"modal\" data-target=\"#AddClientModal\" id=\"btnEditRow\"></a> ';

Comment: OK, I can't invest any more time, but my final comment is this. It seems to me that you're using DataTables, and you're hoping to pass `oObj.aData[0]`, which you expect to be a string containing a location Id. If you used my code and fixed the `instanceOf` syntax error without telling me, it seems that `oObj.aData[0]` isn't being set correctly -- look at how the `oObj` object is being loaded, and fix the error before you try to pass it to `EditRow`. Sorry I couldn't be more help.